# Can't update remote position of player character in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I've recently been trying to set up multiplayer networking for my Godot game using a tutorial I found on YouTube. Despite this I keep getting this error when another player character joins the server, causing the player's position changes to not occur globally.

```
_process_rpc: RPC 'update_remote_position' is not allowed on node /root/Player/1 from: 694666895. Mode is 2, authority is 1.
```

Here is my networking buttons code:

```
extends BoxContainer

var peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()

const ADDRESS = "localhost"
const PORT = 9999
var player_ids = []

func _create_server():
    peer.create_server(PORT)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer
    
    create_player(1)
    
    peer.peer_connected.connect(
        func(new_peer_id):
            await get_tree().create_timer(1).timeout
            rpc("add_newly_connected_player", new_peer_id)
            rpc_id(new_peer_id, "add_previously_connected_players", player_ids)
            
            create_player(new_peer_id)
    )
    
func _join_server():
    peer.create_client(ADDRESS, PORT)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer

func _disconnect():
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = null

func create_player(new_peer_id):
    player_ids.append(new_peer_id)
    var player_instance = preload("res://prefabs/player.tscn").instantiate()
    $/root.add_child(player_instance)
    player_instance.set_multiplayer_authority(new_peer_id)
    player_instance.position = Vector2.ZERO

@rpc
func add_newly_connected_player(new_peer_id):
    create_player(new_peer_id)

@rpc
func add_previously_connected_players(peer_ids):
    for peer_id in peer_ids:
        create_player(peer_id)

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    $JoinButton.pressed.connect(self._join_server)
    $HostButton.pressed.connect(self._create_server)
    $LeaveButton.pressed.connect(self._disconnect)
    
    pass # Replace with function body.
```

and here is my player movement code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var SPEED = 300.0
@export var JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be used with the player character
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

#Get sprite, and marker nodes for animations, projectiles, etc
@onready var sprite = get_node("AnimatedSprite2D")

#Preload fireball scene as prefab
var fireball_scene = preload("res://prefabs/fireball.tscn")

func _ready():
    name = str(get_multiplayer_authority())

#Update the position of the markers where projectiles are spawned
func update_markers():
    var BackMarker = get_node("BackMarker")
    var FrontMarker = get_node("FrontMarker")
    
    FrontMarker.position = Vector2(self.position.x - 70, self.position.y - 40)
    BackMarker.position = Vector2(self.position.x + 70, self.position.y - 40)

#Function that handles projectile input
func projectile():
    #Update the position of the markers for projectiles
    update_markers()
    
    #Define fireball variables and get marker nodes for positioning
    var fireball_instance
    var fireball_animations
    var BackMarker = get_node("BackMarker")
    var FrontMarker = get_node("FrontMarker")

    #Check for inputs in the "projectile" input map
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("projectile"):
        #Instantiate fireball and get animatios
        fireball_instance = fireball_scene.instantiate()
        fireball_animations = fireball_instance.get_node("Sprite2D/AnimationPlayer")
        
        #Add the instance to the scene as a child of the root node
        get_node("/root").add_child(fireball_instance)
        
        #Place the fireball in the corresponding marker and play the "shoot" animation
        if sprite.scale.x > 0:
            fireball_instance.position = FrontMarker.position
            fireball_animations.play("shoot")
        elif sprite.scale.x < 0:
            fireball_instance.position = BackMarker.position
            fireball_animations.play("shoot_right")
        
        #Wait for the animation to finish and then erase the fireball
        await get_tree().create_timer(fireball_animations.current_animation_length).timeout
        fireball_instance.queue_free()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if is_multiplayer_authority():
        # Add the gravity.
        if not is_on_floor():
            velocity.y += gravity * delta

        # Handle Jump.
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
            velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        
        #Manage projectile input
        projectile()

        # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
        var direction = Input.get_axis("left", "right")
        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            sprite.play("walk")
        else:
            velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
            sprite.stop()
            sprite.play("idle")
        
        #Flip sprite depending on facing direction
        if velocity.x > 0:
            sprite.scale.x = -0.555
        if velocity.x < 0:
            sprite.scale.x = 0.555
        
        #Execute velocity instructions
        move_and_slide()
        rpc("update_remote_position", global_position)

@rpc("unreliable")
func update_remote_position(authority_position):
    self.global_position = authority_position
```

Thanks in advance!(let me know if you need any more info)